# compare lines in a file with a string

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to see if my list already has a specific user in it. I should get "match found" printed out but I don't. I thought the problem was in my php-file so i created a text file with the same contents but it still doesn't find the match.

```
import urllib2
server = "10.20.68.235"
var = "patrik"
file = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+server+"/list-text.php")

for line in file:
        if line == var:
                print "match found"
        print line,

print "done"
```

Here is the output im getting:

```
someguy
user
patrik
juniper
ftpsecure
momeunier
done
```

Comment: try line.strip() == var

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create the following file `xx.in`:

```
test line 1
test line 2
```

and run the following Python program, you'll see *exactly* why the match is failing:

```
file = open('xx.in')
for line in file:
    print '[%s]' % (line)
```

The output is:

```
[test line 1
]
[test line 2
]
```

showing that the newline characters are being left on the line when they're read in. If you want them stripped off, you can use:

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

This will remove all newline characters from the *end* of the string and, unlike `strip()`, will not affect any other whitespace characters at either the start or end.