# Trying to find object in list but it just doesn't work

Tags: python, list

So my project consists of trying to get all the data from this file (data.txt) and filter to find the values of last week, so I used `datetime.timedelta` to get a list with all the dates from the current day and the 6 days before, but when I try to find the date of data in the file and compare it with the dates in the 'last week list', it doesn't work, even though they are both strings and are both in the same pattern YY-MM-DD. They are identical but it always returns false. This is my first post so maybe it is kinda confusing, but if you could help me out it would be great.

This is what the data.txt is, it contains the session duration, start time, ending time and current date of the session.

```
0.6351542472839355;16:12:46.275692;16:12:46.910832;2020-07-08
0.24894213676452637;16:12:47.867543;16:12:48.116485;2020-07-08
0.2877843379974365;16:12:48.824725;16:12:49.112509;2020-07-08
200.29360198974609375;16:12:49.754576;16:12:50.048178;2020-07-08
200.25270724296569824;16:12:50.636086;16:12:50.888793;2020-07-08
3000.2298729419708252;16:12:51.469012;16:12:51.698880;2020-07-08

SESSION DURATION ; START TIME ; END TIME ; DATE
```

```
def last_week_hours():
    today = date.today()
    lastweekhours = 0
    weeklist = []
    for i in range(0,7):
        wdate = today - timedelta(days=i)
        weeklist.append(str(wdate))
    db = open('data.txt', 'rt')
    for line in db:
        info = line.split(';')
        sdate = info[3]
        sduration = info[0]
        if sdate in weeklist:
            print('sdate is in weeklist')
            lastweekhours += sduration
```

Comment: I updated it with the part of the file

Comment: The lines read from your file will end with newline characters.  After the split, that newline ends up in `sdate`, making it unequal to anything in `weeklist`.  Apply `.strip()` to either `line` or `sdate` to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. In the future, please provide a [mre], which means including the desired output, actual output, and full code (yours never calls `last_week_hours`). As well it seems like the timedelta part is irrelevant.

Comment: wow thank you man, it worked, I didn't even remember I put the \n at the end.

Comment: Duplicate: [compare lines in a file with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24285306/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest maybe doing a sdate.strip() in your 'for line in db:' loop, in order to remove any leading or trailing whitespace that may or may not be messing up the equality check.